# ios swift facebook button login to the application

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I have a button in my design which shows login to `Facebook`. The `iOS` application is in `Swift`. My question is how to integrate `Facebook` in my application. I have gone through many tutorials and i am able to integrate the facebook login and the button also occurs automaticaly. I need to know how should i solve my task.

```
import UIKit


class Signin: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var useremail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

@IBAction func fblogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

@IBAction func signin(_ sender: Any) {

    let loginPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp") as! SignUp
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)

}

@IBAction func forgotpassword(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {
}

}
```

Comment: What do you want to know? Do you want to understand how it works?

Comment: i am a beginner in swift and ios programming, i want to know that how to integrate fb? with in this @ibaction func fblogin part i have to write the code or what? i followed the tutorials and i am able to make a single view app it shows logging in now the situation is i am having a button in a designed app and i need to work out with it only.

Comment: Understood your problem. But fortunately/unfortunately, believe me, Facebook documentation is the best to follow to learn.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: Check this article once: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/facebook-integration-using-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out ["Simplicity"](https://github.com/SimplicityMobile/Simplicity) - it's really easy to implement.

Requires XCode 8+ / Swift 3+

Check it out on github - you have all you need to use it.

Comment: thankyou for your valuable reply but i am doing this for a client. shoul i simply add this to my project? i do'n have much explosure i am just an intern.

Answer (score 0):

In order to login via facebook, you need to integrate Facebook SDK in your application.
Follow this link for integration :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

If you just want to login via facebook and don't need any other services of fb, then just integrate FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit.

Comment: thankyou will implement and tell you what help it made.

Answer (score 0):

Right place to learn any social login integration into your app is their **official docs**. So refer `Facebook` official docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login).

For getting basic idea about implementation other than Facebook docs, please visit this [SocialLogin](https://github.com/karthironald/SocialLogin-iOS/tree/master/SocialLogin) project. Here you will get simple implementation for `Facebook Login`.

Thanks.